# Appending to json file without writing entire file

Tags: json, file, go

I have a json which contains one its attributes value as an array and I need to keep appending values to the array and write to a file. Is there a way I could avoid rewrite of the existing data and only append the new values?

*----- Moving next question on different thread ---------------
what is recommended way for writing big data sets onto the file incremental file write or file dump at the end process?*

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions. Please ask one question per post. Your JSON question is great; the second question about writing big data sets should be a second question--and it needs to be clarified.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the file is a JSON array, or can it be a stream of values?  The latter makes the answer to both of your questions simpler.

Comment: @Flimzy have edited the question.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes it is like a requirement as I have a structure like 
{"list": [{"name": "Batman"}, {"name": "Superman"}]}
and I want to keep appending  to this "list" attribute value.

Comment: @Abhsk Please update the question with the Go types involved and this example JSON.  It's not clear at all from the question the the top-level of the file is a JSON object, not a JSON array.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution makes the most sense if the existing JSON is actually an array, or if it's an object that has an array as the last or only pair, as in your case. Otherwise, you're *inserting* instead of appending. You probably don't want to *read* the entire file either.

One approach is not much different than what you were thinking, but handles several details

1. Read the end of the file to verify that it "ends with an array"
2. Retain that part
3. Position the file at that ending array bracket
4. Take the output from a standard encoder for an array of new data, dropping its opening bracket, and inserting a comma if necessary
5. The end of the the new output replaces the original ending array bracket
6. Tack the rest of the tail back on

```golang
import (
        "bytes"
        "errors"
        "io"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
        "regexp"
        "unicode"
)

const (
        tailCheckLen = 16
)

var (
        arrayEndsObject = regexp.MustCompile("(\\[\\s*)?](\\s*}\\s*)$")
        justArray       = regexp.MustCompile("(\\[\\s*)?](\\s*)$")
)

type jsonAppender struct {
        f               *os.File
        strippedBracket bool
        needsComma      bool
        tail            []byte
}

func (a jsonAppender) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
        trimmed := 0
        if !a.strippedBracket {
                t := bytes.TrimLeftFunc(b, unicode.IsSpace)
                if len(t) == 0 {
                        return len(b), nil
                }
                if t[0] != '[' {
                        return 0, errors.New("not appending array: " + string(t))
                }
                trimmed = len(b) - len(t) + 1
                b = t[1:]
                a.strippedBracket = true
        }
        if a.needsComma {
                a.needsComma = false
                n, err := a.f.Write([]byte(", "))
                if err != nil {
                        return n, err
                }
        }
        n, err := a.f.Write(b)
        return trimmed + n, err
}

func (a jsonAppender) Close() error {
        if _, err := a.f.Write(a.tail); err != nil {
                defer a.f.Close()
                return err
        }
        return a.f.Close()
}

func JSONArrayAppender(file string) (io.WriteCloser, error) {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(file, os.O_RDWR, 0664)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        pos, err := f.Seek(0, io.SeekEnd)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        if pos < tailCheckLen {
                pos = 0
        } else {
                pos -= tailCheckLen
        }
        _, err = f.Seek(pos, io.SeekStart)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        tail, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }

        hasElements := false

        if len(tail) == 0 {
                _, err = f.Write([]byte("["))
                if err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                }
        } else {
                var g [][]byte
                if g = arrayEndsObject.FindSubmatch(tail); g != nil {
                } else if g = justArray.FindSubmatch(tail); g != nil {
                } else {
                        return nil, errors.New("does not end with array")
                }

                hasElements = len(g[1]) == 0
                _, err = f.Seek(-int64(len(g[2])+1), io.SeekEnd) // 1 for ]
                if err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                }
                tail = g[2]
        }

        return jsonAppender{f: f, needsComma: hasElements, tail: tail}, nil
}
```

Usage is then like in this test fragment

```
    a, err := JSONArrayAppender(f)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }

    added := []struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
    }{
            {"Wonder Woman"},
    }
    if err = json.NewEncoder(a).Encode(added); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = a.Close(); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }
```

You can use whatever settings on the Encoder you want. The only hard-coded part is handling `needsComma`, but you can add an argument for that.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON array is simple you can use something like the following code. In this code, I create JSON array manually.

```
type item struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Create("hello.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fd.Write([]byte{'['})
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        b, err := json.Marshal(item{
            "parham",
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if i != 0 {
            fd.Write([]byte{','})
        }
        fd.Write(b)
    }
    fd.Write([]byte{']'})
}
```

If you want to have a valid array in each step you can write ']' at the end of each iteration and then seek back on the start of the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was thinking on the similar lines but then after every iteration I have to do following steps
1. Remove ']}' -- since my json structure is _'{"list": [{"name": "Batman"}, {"name": "Superman"}]}'_
2. Add new item 
3. Re-add  ']}'

But this could result in invalid json if any of these steps fails. Also doing this manually could increase the chances errors.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about these issues. @Abhsk